# dynamically resolving types from an Assembly loaded through Reflection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection

Consider the following code in a DLL:

```
public class ReceivingClass
{
    private Assembly myAssembly;
    private Type typeOfClass;
    public ReceivingClass()
    {
        myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"E:\VSProjects\TestDynamicLinking\MyLib\bin\Debug\MyLib.dll");
        //Can I use this type somehow to resolve the type in the below method?
        typeOfClass = myAssembly.GetType("ExportedClass");
    }
    public bool ReceiveMethod(ExportedClass classobj)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So, the problem is that in the `ReceiveMethod` above, `ExportedClass` is a class which is defined in the Assembly that I dynamically loaded in the Constructor. So, can I somehow resolve the type of `ExportedClass` such that I don't have to use `dynamic`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some choices you have are either

- Reference the actual assembly (probably not possible in your case as you load it dynamically),
- Use a shared interface that the type implements (only if you can edit the loaded assembly),
- or Use dynamic / reflection

I would usually use the second approach. Just define an interface that ExportedClass implements in another (shared) assembly. Then you can try to cast the created instance to that interface. like that:

```
ISomeInterface obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfClass) as ISomeInterface;
```

Of course, that is assuming that you have control over the referenced library. Or if you are defining a plugin infrastructure or something like that, you should include that as a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a method signature in your code like so:

```
public bool ReceiveMethod(ExportedClass classobj)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

That means you're already referencing the assembly. You don't need to load it dynamically. Also with reflection you get the type. You then have to create object of the type.

dynamic can only hold reference to object of any type but it doesn't instantiate the object for you.
Suppose you create instance with [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) then you can easily cast the resulting object into the specific type you know it is.

But again if you know the specific type then you may already have reference to the assembly unless you're accepting a shared interface or base class of the object but you said the method accepts object of a class that is defined in that assembly so you're already referencing the assembly.

If I asume that your method signature is not like that and you want to know what your options are then like @Botz3000 said you can use reflection, dynamic or a shared interface.